# iptables unable to block local ssh connection

Tags: ssh, networking, iptables

Here is my question: Why is iptables unable to prevent SSH from connecting to localhost?

A more detailed description follows.

During a process of experimentation with iptables I came across the following curiosity that I'd like to understand. Even when I set every policy to DROP, I'm still able to access the machine locally via SSH.

Here is what I'm doing.

First I use `iptables` to set all POLICY values to DROP:

```
cat <<HEREDOC | sudo iptables-restore

*filter
:INPUT DROP
:FORWARD DROP
:OUTPUT DROP
COMMIT

*mangle
:PREROUTING DROP
:INPUT DROP
:FORWARD DROP
:OUTPUT DROP
:POSTROUTING DROP
COMMIT

*nat
:PREROUTING DROP
:POSTROUTING DROP
:OUTPUT DROP
:INPUT DROP
COMMIT

*raw
:PREROUTING DROP
:OUTPUT DROP
COMMIT
HEREDOC
```

Then I try to connect via SSH:

```
ssh localhost
```

And, much to my surprise, this works! I'm presented with a new shell session as if there were no firewall. As a sanity check I then try to ping localhost, which results in the following error message:

```
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
```

This seems to suggest that the firewall is in fact operational. Finally I try to SSH using an IP address

```bsh
ssh 127.0.0.1
```

This hangs, as I would have expected.

So my best guest is that SSH is doing something differently when it's passed the string "localhost" as an argument - something that doesn't actually involve the loopback interface. If this is in fact the case then my question becomes, "What exactly is ssh doing?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probably, `localhost` resolves to an IPv6 address (`::1`) which is not filtered by `iptables` (use `ip6tables`).

The output of:

```
strace -e connect ssh localhost
```

will tell you what IP address and what protocol are used.

Comment: Modern kernels usually prefer IPv6.  Try the command `ping6 localhost` which should connect to "::1"

Comment: @xhienne You nailed it. I'm embarrassed to confess that IPv6 didn't even occur to me.

Answer (score 4):

as suggested by xhienne it is probably connecting to ::1. you can try **ssh -vv localhost** and see full debug output of ssh.

```
    # ssh -vvv localhost
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
```